# how to json data fix render in react native

Tags: json

I am really a beginner.

in renderItem ()
If {item.value} is 10 or less, I want to render the output as "Text".

How can I do this?

Thank you for reading the question. I will study hard

I pray that you will be safe and healthy from the corona virus.

```
  renderItem = ({item}) => {
       return(
      <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
      <View style={{marginBottom:10}}>
      <Text>
        {item.from} 
        {item.to} 
        {item.value}
      </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
    )
  }


  componentDidMount(){
    const url = 'http://api-ropsten.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0x3A19E068Ea11b4D10D4516823eA9482fE70F1c52&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&sort=asc&apikey=IQN5KP8AKJ9WFTYNGZRJE7W3QHXPT4S65H'
    fetch(url)
    .then((response)=>response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      this.setState({
        dataSource:responseJson.result
      })
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
      console.log(error)
    })
  }


  render(){
    return(
      <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>

        <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
        />

      </View>
    )
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need learn javascript and es6 specially, will help you a lot in future. For now you can check in renderItem method if value is less than 10 or not and then return the desired output.

```
renderItem = ({item}) => {
   if(item.value < 10){

   return(
  <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
  <View style={{marginBottom:10}}>
  <Text>
   {The text you want}
  </Text>
  </View>
  </View>)

   } else {
          return <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
  <View style={{marginBottom:10}}>
  <Text>
   {some value}
  </Text>
  </View>
  </View>

     }
```

Comment: thank you. :)
However
Not the way you want it.
Even if item.value is 10 or higher, it must be rendered.
If it is less than 10, I want to print it in different text.